# Pydantic input model for partial updates

Tags: python, pydantic

I am using Pydantic to validate data inputs in a server. Pydantic models:

- User: for common fields
- UserIn: user input data to create new account
- UserInDB: to hash password and include extra fields like `created_at`
- UserOut: to output created/updated user data

Now how can I utilize the model `UserIn` for user account partial updates? so that `None` fields are excluded. Or do I have to rewrite it again and make every field optional?

```
class User(BaseModel):

    name_first :          str = Field(...)
    name_last :           Optional[str] = None
    mobile :              int = Field(..., description="It has to be 8 digits and starts with either 9 or 7", example="99009900")
    
    email :               Optional[EmailStr] = None
    
    gender:               Literal['m', 'f'] = Field(..., example="m")
    birth_date:           datetime.date
    preferred_language :  Literal['ar', 'en'] = Field(..., example="ar")
    newsletter :          bool = Field(...)


    @validator('mobile')
    def number_has_to_start_with_9_or_7(cls, v):
        if str(v)[:1] !="9" and str(v)[:1] !="7":
            raise ValueError('Mobile number must start with 9 or 7')
        if len(str(v)) !=8:
            raise ValueError('Mobile number must be 8 digits')
        return v


class UserIn(User):
    password: str = Field(...)

class UserInDB(UserIn):
    mobile_otp:           int = Field(...)
    bitrole:              int = Field(...)
    created_at:           datetime.datetime
    updated_at:           datetime.datetime

class UserOut(User):
    id:                   int
    mobile_otp:           int
    bitrole:              int
    mobile_confirmed :    bool
    email_confirmed :     bool
    disabled :            bool
    created_at:           datetime.datetime
    updated_at:           datetime.datetime

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately this is a problem that has been already faced by quite a lot of people (me included).

There is no simple way of handling it out of the box and as far as I know.

Here are some solutions proposed to bypass the problem, although not completely, on github

https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/990#issuecomment-645961530

**MY SOLUTION**

I use pydantic with [fastapi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) and partial updates of resources are quite common. Due to the limitation of pydantic I ask the user to resubmit all the values, filling correctly the pydantic model and then update all the fields that can be updated.

It's not ideal, I know, but it seems to work

***UPDATE***

I've found another possible solution. Basically, retrieve the old data, update it, and write the updated data (much better than my solution).

See fastapi docs https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-updates/#partial-updates-with-patch

Warning: Partial updates with nested object are currently not implemented in pydantic. See https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/4177

Comment: The FastAPI approach is kind of acceptable to me. If you notice, all the fields in the Pydantic update model/schema are optional. The first point here is that you can not use a Pydantic create model for partial updates. There has to be a second model with all the fields optional. 2nd point is that you do not need to retrieve stored data as in that example. You can simply partially update a db record using query update.

Comment: I know, but my approach is from way before the PATCH solution come out. I haven't checked the docs in a while, which I did after (and hence the update). Fastapi uses pydantic for data validation, so it's out of pydantic's scope to provide updates for db records.